# Why does defining the argument types for __eq__ throw a MyPy type error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, typechecking, mypy

I'm using Python 3.5.1 and the newly released [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/) v0.4.1 static type analyzer.

I have some more complex code that I've reduced down to this simplest possible python class needed to reproduce the error:

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, value: int=5) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other: MyObject) -> bool:
        return self.value == other.value
```

Running the type checker `mypy test.py` produces the following error:

```
test.py: note: In class "MyObject":
test.py:5: error: Argument 1 of "__eq__" incompatible with supertype "object"
```

My theory based on [these docs](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#complex-type-tests) is that `.__eq__(...)` and `.__ne__(...)` on `object` already have argument types defined, which are clashing with my subclass's redefinition of these types.  My question is how to I define these types to make sure `__eq__` is type-checked with my chosen type.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`==` is supposed to take arbitrary other objects, not just objects of your type. If it doesn't recognize the other object, it should return `NotImplemented`:

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, value: int=5) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, MyObject):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.value == other.value
```

`NotImplemented` isn't an instance of `bool`, but mypy seems to have a weird special case for that. It accepts this code as-is.

On Python 3.10 and up, you can use `types.NotImplementedType` to be more explicit about the NotImplemented possibility:

```
from types import NotImplementedType

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, value: int=5) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool | NotImplementedType:
        if not isinstance(other, MyObject):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.value == other.value
```

Also, if you need to refer to `MyObject` for type hints inside its own body, you need to use a string, `'MyObject'` instead of `MyObject`. `MyObject` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Re: referring to `MyObject` inside it's own body, I've done that elsewhere in my code without quoting and I get no errors from MyPy: https://github.com/pirate/py-data/blob/master/recursive_descent_parser.py#L78

Comment: @NickSweeting: Did you run it? [You should get an error when you try to run it.](http://ideone.com/vk5VX6)

Comment: Ah, thanks @user2357112, I only tried mypy-ing it and neglected to actually run it.  Changing it to strings worked.

Comment: One thing I just realized, I've never seen functions return exception types before (as opposed to `raise`ing them), is this standard practice?

Comment: @NickSweeting: NotImplemented is not an exception. You're thinking of NotImplementedError. Returning NotImplemented is how you signal that your special method doesn't assign a meaning to an operation, so Python should try the other object's method. I've heard it's a return value instead of an exception for speed purposes.

Comment: Is the return type correct? Technically this function returns `bool | NotImplemented`.

Comment: @knite: It's not correct, but it's what mypy wants. (Also NotImplemented isn't a type.)

Answer (score 5):

Your reading of the docs is right -- you need to give the method (`__eq__`) the same signature as it has already in the base class (`object`), or else a more permissive one.

The reason for that is that because your `MyObject` is a subtype of `object`, a `MyObject` could be passed anywhere that expects an `object`... which means that that code could compare it with any other `object`, and there's no legitimate way for the type checker to complain. So, to reflect that, your `__eq__` has to be written to expect any `object`.

What you can do is right up front in the method's body, check the type and return (or raise an exception):

```
if not isinstance(other, MyObject):
  return False
```

Then as [those docs say](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#complex-type-tests), Mypy is smart enough that after that check, it will know that `other` is a `MyObject` and treat it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing the `other` object, I would use `isinstance` to define a behaviour per object type. This also enables type hinting, as it defines the type of `other` on the line below, and it allows to define different behaviour when handling various classes equalities

```py
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, value: int=5) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        if isinstance(other, MyObject):
            return self.value == other.value
        elif isinstance(other, MyOtherObject):
            return self.value == other.other_value
        return false
```

Answer (score -1):

The test using "isinstance()" only works if there's no inheritance, if there's is you either need to override **eq** in derived classes or use if type(self) != type(other)